# Жирный шрифт на андроид

Tags: android, java

Как можно сделать жирный шрифт в одном textView, который может меняться местами?

Comment: Я не правильно изъяснился, как можно сделать, чтобы в одном TextView разные шрифты, одно слово - жирным, другое слово - другим шрифтом.

Comment: в таком случае никакие форумы не нужны, если есть гугл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно, смотрите в сторону `SpannableString`. Если вкратце, то концепт такой: строка рассматривается состоящей из нескольких спанов, то бишь [стилей](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/CharacterStyle.html), которые можно накладывать на разные участки строки.

Например:

```
 TextView tv;
 //blah-blah
 SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hello World");
 StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD); // жирный спан
 sb.setSpan(bss, 0, 5, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); // делаем жирным слово Hello
 tv.setText(sb);
```

Comment: @Barmaley а можно ли как то сделать в нескольких местах жирными слова, я делаю setSpan два раза а он делает жирным только последнее изменение.